# How can I incorporate inline CSS styles and stylesheets relating to one page only when using the PHP 'header'?

Tags: php, css, header-files, head

I have a 'header.php' file and I am incorporating it into my html pages using the following code:

```
<?php /*
            $pageTitle = "Home";
            $section = "Home";
            include('inc/header.php');
            ?>
```

The PHP header file contains a number of CSS stylesheets. Some of these CSS stylesheets I only want to include on one page - e.g. I only want to include 'index.css' on the page 'index.php'. How can I include these stylesheets when I am using the same 'header.php' file in every page of the site?

Is there a way of specifying these styles in the individual pages themselves, rather than in the header file? If so, can these styles be placed in another  element, even if the  element has already been used (opened and closed) in the header file?

Here is the code for my 'header.php' file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle ?> || Young Academy </title>

    <meta name="description" content="Based in Pinner in North-West London, the Young Academy has been creating the highest standard of musical and dramatic education for 30 years.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Piano, Flute, Music Theory, Singing, Violin, Concerts, Pinner, Middlesex, Harrow, Teacher">
    <meta name="author" content="Barbara Young">


    <!--Stylesheets!-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/text.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/960_16_col.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/contact.css"/>


    <!--Google fonts!-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500,500italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bgaudioplayer.css"/>**
    <!--Meta tags!-->

    <meta name="author" content="Robert Young" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="2013 by Robert Young" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Music lessons, Pinner, music tuition, piano lessons, speech and drama, London" />
    <meta name="description" content="Site of the Young Academy, a private music tuition business based in Pinner" />


<script src="../js/modernizr.custom.63826.js"></script>
<script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">

        <div class="container_16 clearfix">
            <ul class="nav grid_16 alpha">
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Home") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="index.php" accesskey="1"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "About Us") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="about_us.php" accesskey="2"> About </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "What We Do") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="what_we_do.php" accesskey="3"> What We Do </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Enrolement") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="enrolement.php" accesskey="4"> Enrolement </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Contact Us") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="contact.php" accesskey="5"> Contact Us </a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="http://youngacademyblog.blogspot.co.uk/" accesskey="6"> Blog </a></li>-->
            </ul>


            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="img/Logo original.gif" alt="The Young Academy"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "grid_4 alpha">

            <div class="telephone grid_4 alpha">
                <img src="img/phone_icon_white.png" alt="small telephone logo" class="align-left small" />
                <p> +44 (0)20 8866 3813 </P>
            </div>
            <div class="timezone">

                    <p><?php
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
                    mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970);
                    echo date('l, d F Y'); 
                    ?> </p>

                    <!--<form action="http://www.example.com/login.php">
                        <p>

                            <input type="text name=search" size="20+" id="search" value="Search this site"
                        </p>
                    </form>!-->



            </div>

        </div>


                <ul class="secondmenu grid_6 push_3">

                    <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Musical Glossary") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="glossary.php">Musical Glossary </a></li>
                    <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "FAQ") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>

                <ul>






    </div>
```

I want to include the stylesheets in bold only on the index.php page. Can I include them like this:

```
<?php 

            include('inc/header.php');
            ?>


<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bgaudioplayer.css"/>

</head>






                    <article class="content">

                        <p class="grid_9 alpha"><i>Outstanding vocal and instrumental tuition.</i></p>

                    </article>

                    <article class="second-content">

                    <p class="grid_6 alpha omega">Develop a passion for music.</p>

                    </article>

                    <article class="third-content">

                    <p class="grid_5 alpha omega">Become a virtuoso.</p>

                    </article>
```

etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Robert.

Comment: That was supposed to say: 'can these styles be placed in another head element'

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried the above code and it happens to work! You can include head tags in both the header.php file and the main (index.php) site file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

long story short you need some sort of router. but Looking at your code it seems like you may not have a firm grasp on Object Oriented Programming. what you can do though is look at the URI with [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) if the string is lets say /about then load in resources for about-stylesheet.css.

Comment: [user2191622](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17734856/1090725) answer is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an if else statement that replaces the link to your CSS and refers to the unique variable you sent for the page you want to pull the CSS in for:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="

<?php
if ($pageTitle == "Home") {

echo "css/index.css";


else ($pageTitle == "SomeOtherTitle") {

echo "css/relativelnk.css";
}

?>
   "/>
```